# Employees and departments with groups database schema advice

Tags: php, mysql

What I got is

Tables:

```
employee {id, name, phone, dep_link[fk]} 
department {id, name}
groups {id, name}
employees_groups {id, emp_id_link[fk] ,group_id_link[fk]}
departments_groups {id, dep_id_link[fk], group_id_link[fk]}
```

Logic:

1. Every employee can be in one department and the department can have many employees. (one to many is the choice as i did with the `{dep_link[fk]}`)
2. Each employee can be in many groups and a group can have many employees.
3. Each department can be in many groups and a group can have many departments.

Is what I did with the tables and the relations right? I have two departments (IT,Archives) they are part of the group (All). After I add the relation in to the departments_groups table how can I retrieve the employees of these departments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for example i got two departments (IT,Archives) they are part of the
>   group (All) after i add the relation in to the departments_groups
>   table how can i retrieve the employees of these departments ?

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employee.dep_link 
IN (SELECT dep_id_link FROM departments_group INNER JOIN groups 
    ON groups.id = group_id_link AND groups.name = 'All')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of what your looking for:

```
select e.id
      ,e.name
      ,e.phone
from employee e
    ,group g
    ,employee_groups eg
where e.id = eg.emp_id_link
  and g.id = eg.group_id_link
  and g.name = "all"
```

Hope it Helps.  :)

Comment: That doesn't get the employees of the departments_group table.